# No template specialization in the clang AST if a header is missing

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, c++-templates

Observation: Clang AST don't contain any template specialisation if a header file is missing. It is true even when the template got nothing to do with the header file.

For example,

```cpp
#include "unknown_header.h"

template<class T>
T add(T x, T y) {return x + y;}

void sum(void)
{
  add<double>(5.0, 6.0);
}
```

generate the `FunctionTemplateDecl` instance, which doesn't contain specialisation for type `double`.

But if we get rid of "unknown_header.h", resulting in successful compilation, we can see the specialisation using type double. The specialisation can be seen below after removing the header.

```cpp
|-FunctionTemplateDecl 0x55ec327d83e8 <tmp.cpp:1:1, line:2:31> col:3 add
| |-TemplateTypeParmDecl 0x55ec327d80f0 <line:1:10, col:16> col:16 referenced class depth 0 index 0 T
| |-FunctionDecl 0x55ec327d8348 <line:2:1, col:31> col:3 add 'T (T, T)'
| | |-ParmVarDecl 0x55ec327d81c0 <col:7, col:9> col:9 referenced x 'T'
| | |-ParmVarDecl 0x55ec327d8238 <col:12, col:14> col:14 referenced y 'T'
| | `-CompoundStmt 0x55ec327d8580 <col:17, col:31>
| |   `-ReturnStmt 0x55ec327d8570 <col:18, col:29>
| |     `-BinaryOperator 0x55ec327d8550 <col:25, col:29> '<dependent type>' '+'
| |       |-DeclRefExpr 0x55ec327d8510 <col:25> 'T' lvalue ParmVar 0x55ec327d81c0 'x' 'T'
| |       `-DeclRefExpr 0x55ec327d8530 <col:29> 'T' lvalue ParmVar 0x55ec327d8238 'y' 'T'
| `-FunctionDecl 0x55ec327d8ae8 <col:1, col:31> col:3 used add 'double (double, double)'
|   |-TemplateArgument type 'double'
|   | `-BuiltinType 0x55ec327923c0 'double'
|   |-ParmVarDecl 0x55ec327d8960 <col:7, col:9> col:9 used x 'double':'double'
|   |-ParmVarDecl 0x55ec327d89d8 <col:12, col:14> col:14 used y 'double':'double'
|   `-CompoundStmt 0x55ec327d8da8 <col:17, col:31>
|     `-ReturnStmt 0x55ec327d8d98 <col:18, col:29>
|       `-BinaryOperator 0x55ec327d8d78 <col:25, col:29> 'double' '+'
|         |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x55ec327d8d48 <col:25> 'double':'double' <LValueToRValue>
|         | `-DeclRefExpr 0x55ec327d8d08 <col:25> 'double':'double' lvalue ParmVar 0x55ec327d8960 'x' 'double':'double'
|         `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x55ec327d8d60 <col:29> 'double':'double' <LValueToRValue>
|           `-DeclRefExpr 0x55ec327d8d28 <col:29> 'double':'double' lvalue ParmVar 0x55ec327d89d8 'y' 'double':'double'
```

Question: What stops clang from generating the template specialisation if the header is missing?

Comment: Would it still happen if the template function is not right next to the include? As if there are some functions/declarations in between the include and the template function?

Comment: @thedemons Yes! I tried adding `int x =0;` in-between the two.

Comment: A missing header is not a recoverable error, so I suppose Clang just gives up at that point. You could try adding empty files for each missing header.

Comment: To put that another way, how could Clang know that a header has nothing to do with the template, if it can't read the header? For you, the filename is a hint, but for Clang it's just a filename.

Comment: What @rici said is reasonable, you could try to add a dummy `unknown_header.h`

Comment: I like the idea of creating an empty header file. I can confirm it works

Comment: My guess would be the missing header is found during the parsing stage, as the parsing stage fails the code generation is skipped and templates aren't instantiated

Comment: I wonder why missing a header file stops the generation of the template specialisation, but an empty file doesn’t have the same outcome?

Comment: Because empty headers are legal and missing headers are an error. See my comment above: if a header is missing, Clang has to assume that it is missing relevant input. If the header is empty, there's nothing to do.